# Installing OpenJDK 7 (JRE) but only policytools found in ./jre/bin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-installation, apt, java

I'm trying to install Java 7 onto my Ubuntu machine through apt-get. I'm issuing the to install using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get openjdk-7-jre
```

apt-get claims a successful install, but I cannot appear to make use of OpenJDK 7. Note: I have also tried headless version and gotten similar results.

I'm a complete novice at Linux but comparing to OpenJDK 6 JRE which I have installed, there should be a java file at the ./jre/bin directory. I.e: A comparison of my OpenJDK 6 and 7 directories.

OpenJDK 6:

```
root/bin/$ pwd
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin
root/bin/$ ll
total 464
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 25 17:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 Dec 19 22:01 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   757 Jul  2 01:38 itweb-settings*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39480 Nov 16 17:28 java*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1260 Jul  2 01:38 javaws*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39472 Nov 16 17:28 keytool*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39552 Nov 16 17:28 orbd*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39552 Nov 16 17:28 pack200*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39480 Nov 16 17:28 policytool*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39472 Nov 16 17:28 rmid*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39480 Nov 16 17:28 rmiregistry*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39480 Nov 16 17:28 servertool*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39560 Nov 16 17:28 tnameserv*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 87280 Nov 16 17:28 unpack200*
```

OpenJDK 7:

```
root/bin/$ pwd
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin
root/bin/$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 25 17:33 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Dec 25 17:33 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6360 Jul 16 03:46 policytool*
```

If this is correct, I am unsure of how to proceed to set Java 7 to be my default Java. If this is incorrect, I am unsure of how to correct this. I have attempted uninstalling and reinstalling with similar results.

EDIT: The output of following commands.

The output of java -version after installation:

```
root/~/$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

The output of dpkg -S $(type java | awk '{print $3}') after installation:

```
root/bin/$ hash -r; dpkg -S $(type java | awk '{print $3}')
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/java.
root/bin/$ ll /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Nov 19 13:40 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java*
```

The output for update-alternatives:

```
root/bin/$ update-alternatives --display java
java - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1061
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java'.
```

---

After uninstalling openjdk-6-jre

```
root/~/$ java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
root/~/$
```

I then attempted to install Java 7 using `apt-get install openjdk-7-jre` but I am now back at the beginning; With Java 6 installed and Java 7 incorrectly installed.

Comment: @Braiam: Edited again. It says no found pattern but there is definitely a `/usr/bin/java` file.

Comment: How about `update-alternatives --display java`?

Comment: You understand the differences b/w OpenJDK and Sun's Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the file listing at [Ubuntu's package file listing](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/openjdk-7-jre/filelist), what is happening is actually expected behaviour, so I'm guessing maybe that the OpenJDK 7 JRE in the apt-get repo isn't intended for command line Linux distro's?

I've instead opted to install Oracle's Java 7 JDK/JRE as [here](http://ksearch.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/install-the-oracle-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-server-12-04-via-the-apt-get-command-line/).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have both java 6 and 7 installed. The easy way to fix this situation could be removing java 6 if you don't need it:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove 'openjdk-6-jre*'
```

Comment: I tried to the uninstall of Java 6, but it failed to find Java and recommended packages for me to install. Seems that Java 7 isn't installed.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the output?